# Create multiple type object in restframework

Tags: django, post, serialization, django-rest-framework

I use restframewotk in django for project! 
I want to when post to this URL(example) :

```
/profiles/
```

Created five object! one in profiles model and fourth in Stories model !
so, i write ProfileViewSet :

```
 class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def create(self, request):

        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
           # StoriesViewSet.create(StoriesViewSet , defualt_stories )
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my question is : how add fourth Stories in my db when one profile posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `StoriesViewSet` for that. Just import your Story model, something like

`from models import Story`

and create 4 stories in a loop:

```
....
serializer.save()

for i in range(4):
   s = Story.objects.create(
          title = "Some story title or what ever",
       )
```